# mapStateToProps wont display state in render

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to display my state in my `render()`

I am referencing my state `this.props.UserDetails.accessCode`

```
    <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>What is your access code</td>
                    <td>
                        {this.props.UserDetails.accessCode}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and using `mapStatetoProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        UserDetails: store,
    };
};
```

My values appear empty? Any ideas?

Comment: you're returning the whole state to the `UserDetails` prop. `const mapStateToProps = ({UserDetails}) => ({UserDetails})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be certain what the shape of your store looks like, but when you write:

```
return {
   UserDetails: store,
};
```

are you sure you don't mean?

```
return {
   UserDetails: store.UserDetails,
};
```